# (Nonunique) Solvability of Sylvester Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, matrix-equations

I am interested in stating existence of solution of a Sylvester equation

$$
AX - XB = C,
$$

where $A$, $B$, $C$, and $X$ are $(n,n)$ matrices.

Existence of a **unique** solution $X$ is given, if $A$ and $B$ do not have an eigenvalue in common.

But what about the nonregular case. Are there results out there, that consider the case where $A$ and $B$ possibly share an eigenvalue.

I am only aware of the equivalence, that there exists a solution $X$, if and only if 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & C \\ 0 & B
\end{bmatrix} \backsim
\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 \\ 0 & B
\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
where $\backsim$ is the equivalence relation. However, this didn't give me much insight into my particular setup.

Comment: Did you look at the proof in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) on the topic? It says there is no solution if $A$ and $B$ have any eigenvalue in common.

Comment: Nonono. It says only that a possible solution can not be unique in this case.

Comment: Really? It literally says there is no solution, unique or non-unique, in the last sentence: "Then $AX+XB=C$ has **no solution** $X$, as is clear from the complex bilinear pairing  $<(AX+XB)v,w>=<Cv,w>=<\overline {w},w>$; the right-hand side is positive whereas the left is zero."

Comment: Ok. I think I am misunderstanding something here. Given $A$ and $B$ that have an eigenvalue in common, are you searching solutions for **any** $C$ of your choice? Or are you perhaps asking what form $C$ must have for $AX-XB=C$ to have a solution? If you are doing the former, then, as the last sentence of the article says, there is at least one $C$ for which you will get no solutions at all. If you are doing the latter, I retract my statements.

Comment: Yes, I was just going through the proof. The difference is in 'for all $C$'. In fact, I have $C$ given and I look for conditions when it admits a solution.